# Serializing Treebeard AL_NODE as JSON using Django Serializer

Tags: django-models, django-treebeard

I can't get Django to serialize the AL_NODE as a modelserializer. Is it possible to serialize AL_NODEs?

Here is my code:

```
class UserSecuritySelectionModelSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = UserSecuritySelectionModel()
    fields = ('hasChildNode', 'classificationNames', 'tgtWeight','currWeight','SSM','ext_model_id')
```

Here is a sample of the data and how it is structured in the database:
[image: Database]

Code in my **views.py**

```
if request.is_ajax() and id is not None:

    rootNode = UserSecuritySelectionModel.objects.get(SSM_id=id, classificationNameNode__isnull=True)

    if not rootNode.is_root():
        node = rootNode.get_root()
        data = serializers.serialize('json', node, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)

userSelectionModelSerializer = UserSecuritySelectionModelSerializers(rootNode)
#data = serializers.serialize('json', [rootNode], use_natural_foreign_keys=True)

return JsonResponse (userSelectionModelSerializer.data, status=201, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You say it's not working but you haven't included any details about the error you are getting.  This makes everything here a guess.

You should just be setting the `model` reference to a class, not actually creating an instance of the model

```
model = UserSecuritySelectionModel()

# should be
class Meta:
    model = UserSecuritySelectionModel
```

Next, I think you should explicitly pass in the instance just to be safe.  It's not required, but it makes your intention clear:

```
UserSecuritySelectionModelSerializers(instance=rootNode)
```

Third, just return a standard `Response`, not a `JsonResponse`, DRF will do the content negotiation for you.  That is why you are using it.

```
return Response(MyLongSerializer(instance=root).data)
```

Finally, is there any reason for sending a 201?  You do not appear to be creating anything in the view.   If you are, then send it like this:

```
return Response(..., status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
```